# android: set datepicker to 1 day previous or next date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I need  date picker to respond according to the button, like if today is 27  and i press previous button, date picker should set to 26  and on next button it should set to 27 again. At present i am reading selected date from date picker and subtracting and adding one in it and then set date picker to new date,

here is code for previous button:

```
 prev_date_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                day=start_date.getDayOfMonth()-1;
                month=start_date.getMonth();
                year=start_date.getYear();




                    start_date.init(year, month, day, null);

                    new BackgroundProcess().execute();

                //}
                //Log.v("prev clicked","out of if");
            }
        });
```

I know its a wrong concept as it needs hard code for all the months, there must be some other way out..

Comment: problem will come when selected date is 1 or end of month

Comment: the savest way to add or subtract day, month, or year from you date is by using Calendar object, which will do the work for you i.e. Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()// this will give you the current date, then you can add or sub, like cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);// to add one day to the calendar or cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);// to sub one day to the calendar

Comment: @Moh.Sukhni i tried what you suggested, but it is not giving me desired results, i have asked another question to publish that code and results, kindly see to it [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502738/android-calendar-is-not-giving-expected-results?noredirect=1#comment27204192_18502738)