# Android Calendar is not giving expected results

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am passing values to calendar instance, but don't know why it is not performing as expected. I want to add one day to a specific date and then use that date.

```
Log.v("data going to calendar==",
  "year="+Integer.parseInt(fy)+
  "month="+Integer.parseInt(fm)-1)+
  "day="+Integer.parseInt(fd)+
  "hh="+Integer.parseInt(fh)+
  "mm="+Integer.parseInt(fmn));

c.set(
  Integer.parseInt(fd),
  Integer.parseInt(fm)-1,
  Integer.parseInt(fy),
  Integer.parseInt(fh),
  Integer.parseInt(fmn));

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);

Log.v("data coming from calendar==", 
   "year = " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
   "month ="+ c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
   "day ="+c.get(Calendar.DATE)+
   "hh="+c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+
   "mm="+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

output is:
data gng to calendar==year = 2013month =7day =29hh=12mm=0

data cmng from calendar==year = 35month =1day =4hh=0mm=0

i run that code by putting comment on code to add one day, but the results are still same except for day, it means adding one day is working perfectly --->
year = 35month =1day =3hh=0mm=0

Comment: What is the output that you are getting? Could you show the log output?

Comment: after editing it and output is shown there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the `set()` method with the wrong parameters. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) the order must be `year`, `month`, `date` as first three parameters and you call it with `date`, `month`, `year` as the first parameters.

If you change your code to

```
c.set(Integer.parseInt(fy),
    Integer.parseInt(fm)-1,
    Integer.parseInt(fd),
    Integer.parseInt(fh),
    Integer.parseInt(fmn));
```

it should work as intended.

The strange values are because it treats `2013` as the day which is approx. 6 years that are added to the date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a day - 24 hours - to a date, add it as milliseconds: 1 day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//Set calendar's fields here
long time = c.getTimeInMilliseconds();
long nextDay = time + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
c.setTimeInMillis(nextDay);
```

Comment: actually it is not the adding one day that is causing any problem, after your answer, i run that code by putting comment on code to add one day, but the esults are still same except for day, it means adding one day is working perfectly ---> year = 35month =1day =3hh=0mm=0